# GLFW multiple window in class

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm new in OpenGL and currently i'm working on my test OpenGL project for OpenGL learning. And one of components of this project is WindowManager. I have tried to add multiple windows creating support, but it does not work the way i want.

When I start my application two windows(let's call it as A-FIRST_WINDOW, B-SECOND_WINDOW) are being created at once, but when I close B window my application still work and it's fine, because A window still be available and I can use it and when I close A window my app is being closed. But if i will close A window first,my B window is being closed too and app is being finished.

P.S:
A window - is created first
B window - is created second

Code ...

WindowManager.hpp

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#define DEFAULT_WIDTH 800
#define DEFAULT_HEIGHT 600
#define DEFAULT_TITLE "Soul Byte Engine Window"

namespace SoulByteEngineCore
{
    namespace WindowManager
    {
        class Window
        {
        public:
            Window(unsigned int width=DEFAULT_WIDTH, unsigned int height=DEFAULT_HEIGHT, const char *title = DEFAULT_TITLE);
        public:
            void Clear(float x_pos, float y_pos, float z_pos);
        public:
            unsigned int GetWidth();
            unsigned int GetHeight();
        public:
            static bool Init();
        public:
            void ShowWindowData();
        public:
            const char* GetTitle();
        public:
            bool SetLogging();
        public:
            void onUpdate();
        public:
            bool ShouldClose();
        public:
            void Destroy();
        private:
            bool CreateWindow();
        private:
            void Update();
        private:
            unsigned int m_windowWidth = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
            unsigned int m_windowHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
        private:
            const char* m_windowTitle = DEFAULT_TITLE;
        private:
            unsigned int OpenGLMajorVersion = 3;
            unsigned int OpenGLMinorVersion = 3;
        private:
            GLFWwindow* m_window_handle = NULL;
        };
    }
}
```

```
#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <WindowManager/WindowManager.hpp>

#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace SoulByteEngineCore
{
    namespace WindowManager
    {
        Window::Window(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const char *title)
            :m_windowWidth{std :: move(width)}
            ,m_windowHeight{std :: move(height)}
            ,m_windowTitle{std :: move(title)}
        {
            CreateWindow();
        }

        void Window::Update()
        {
            glfwSwapBuffers(this->m_window_handle);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        void Window::onUpdate()
        {
            Update();
        }

        void Window::Destroy()
        {
            glfwDestroyWindow(this->m_window_handle);
        }

        bool Window::ShouldClose()
        {
            return glfwWindowShouldClose(this->m_window_handle);
        }

        bool Window::Init()
        {
            if (!glfwInit())
            {
                std::cout << "SoulByteEngine :: CORE :: WINDOW_MANAGER :: ERROR :: CRITICAL :: GLFW CANNOT BE INITIALIZED! " << std::endl;

                return false;
            }
        }

        bool Window::CreateWindow()
        {
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
            m_window_handle = glfwCreateWindow(m_windowWidth, m_windowHeight, m_windowTitle, NULL, NULL);

            if (!m_window_handle)
            {
                std::cout << "SoulByteEngine :: CORE :: WindowManagerModule :: ERROR :: COULD'T CREATE WINDOW" << std::endl;

                return false;
            }

            glfwMakeContextCurrent(this->m_window_handle);

            if (!gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress))
            {
                std::cout << "SoulByteEngine :: CORE :: WINDOW_MANAGER :: ERROR :: CRITICAL :: WINDOW HAS BEEN CREATED, BUT GLAD COULD NOT BE INITIALIZED! " << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        bool Window::SetLogging()
        {
            return false;
        }

        unsigned int Window::GetWidth()
        {
            return this->m_windowWidth;
        }

        unsigned int Window::GetHeight()
        {
            return this->m_windowHeight;
        }

        const char* Window::GetTitle()
        {
            return this->m_windowTitle;
        }

        void Window::ShowWindowData()
        {
            std::cout << "Window Data:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Title: " << this->GetTitle() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Width: " << this->GetWidth() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Height: " << this->GetHeight() << std::endl;
        }

        void Window::Clear(float x_pos, float y_pos, float z_pos)
        {
            glClearColor(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

    }
}
```

Application.cpp

```
#include <WindowManager/WindowManager.hpp>

int main()
{
    if (SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::Window::Init())
    {
        SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::Window first_window(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, "First Fuckin SoulByteEngine Window");
        SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::Window second_window(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, "Second Fuckin SoulByteEngine Window");

        while (!first_window.ShouldClose() || !second_window.ShouldClose())
        {
            if (first_window.ShouldClose() == true)
            {
                first_window.Destroy();
            }
            else
            {
                //first_window.Clear(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                first_window.onUpdate();
            }
            if (second_window.ShouldClose() == true)
            {
                second_window.Destroy();
            }
            else
            {
                //second_window.Clear(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                second_window.onUpdate();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OT: `public:` you don't have to put this in the line above every function. You can have more than 1 `public:` for logical organization.

Comment: I am not sure that you showed enough code as we can't test your problem at all and at the same time there is too much code as we don't need any of the `GetTitle()` , `GetHeight()` ... functions at all.

Comment: @drescherjm, i know that i can use "public" for more than 1 logical organization, but i just like put public above every method or multiple methods.

Comment: @drescherjm, ok. i have forgotten about show you usage code. I gonna fix it

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your architecture: As long as one window is alive, you are destroying the closed window over and over again. In general, you may not call any glfw methods on a window that has been destroyed. So relying on the result of `glfwWindowShouldClose` after destroying it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the comment from the user @BDL (architectural issue).

Since you cannot call the `glfwDestroyWindow` from an callback (only from the main thread) you have to take a different approach.

For that, we need two lists (vector), one of opened (active) and one of closing (should close flag set) windows, e.g.

```
std::vector<GLFWwindow*> opened_windows;
std::vector<GLFWwindow*> closing_windows;
```

both are initially empty and get populated if a window was created successfully or is marked to be destroyed.

On open (whenever you create a window):

```
GLFWwindow *win = createWindow();
if (win) {
    opened_windows.push_back(win);
}
```

For the closing case, we have to establish an on close handler:

```
void window_close_callback(GLFWwindow* win)
{
    //remove window from the opened list
    opened_windows.erase(std::find(..., win));
    //add to garbage list
    closing_windows.push_back(win);
}
```

Then in your main loop:

```
while (!opened_windows.empty()) {
    //1. do your stuff
    //2. process events (which might catch a close event)
    //3. destroy all windows in the garbage
    if (!closing_windows.empty()) {
        //foreach element in list, invoke glfwDestroyWindow
        closing_windows.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who answered my question! Special thanks to @BDL! I understood that my architecture was really bad because i haven't checked is my window closed or not and my Destroy() method  was closing window regardless is my window already closed or not, as you know no actions can be performed with an already closed window and any actions taken with already closed window will cause glfw to crush.

So, i have fixed it:

WindowManager.hpp:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


#define DEFAULT_WIDTH 800
#define DEFAULT_HEIGHT 600
#define DEFAULT_TITLE "Soul Byte Engine Window"

namespace SoulByteEngineCore
{
    namespace WindowManager
    {
        class Window
        {
        public:
            Window(unsigned int width=DEFAULT_WIDTH, unsigned int height=DEFAULT_HEIGHT, const char *title = DEFAULT_TITLE);
        public:
            void Clear(float x_pos, float y_pos, float z_pos);
        public:
            unsigned int GetWidth();
            unsigned int GetHeight();
        public:
            bool IsClosed();
        public:
            static bool Init();
        public:
            void ShowWindowData();
        public:
            const char* GetTitle();
        public:
            bool SetLogging();
        public:
            void onUpdate();
        public:
            bool ShouldClose();
        public:
            void Destroy();
        private:
            bool CreateWindow();
        private:
            void Update();
        private:
            unsigned int m_windowWidth = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
            unsigned int m_windowHeight = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
        private:
            const char* m_windowTitle = DEFAULT_TITLE;
        private:
            bool m_isClosed = false;
        private:
            unsigned int OpenGLMajorVersion = 3;
            unsigned int OpenGLMinorVersion = 3;
        private:
            GLFWwindow* m_window_handle = NULL;
        };
    }
}
```

WindowManager.cpp:

```
#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <WindowManager/WindowManager.hpp>

#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace SoulByteEngineCore
{
    namespace WindowManager
    {
        Window::Window(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const char *title)
            :m_windowWidth{std :: move(width)}
            ,m_windowHeight{std :: move(height)}
            ,m_windowTitle{std :: move(title)}
        {
            CreateWindow();
        }

        void Window::Update()
        {
            glfwSwapBuffers(this->m_window_handle);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        void Window::onUpdate()
        {
            Update();
        }

        void Window::Destroy()
        {
            if (!m_isClosed)
            {
                m_isClosed = true;
                glfwDestroyWindow(this->m_window_handle);
            }
        }

        bool Window::ShouldClose()
        {
            return glfwWindowShouldClose(this->m_window_handle);
        }

        bool Window::Init()
        {
            if (!glfwInit())
            {
                std::cout << "SoulByteEngine :: CORE :: WINDOW_MANAGER :: ERROR :: CRITICAL :: GLFW CANNOT BE INITIALIZED! " << std::endl;

                return false;
            }
        }

        bool Window::CreateWindow()
        {
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
            glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
            m_window_handle = glfwCreateWindow(m_windowWidth, m_windowHeight, m_windowTitle, NULL, NULL);

            if (!m_window_handle)
            {
                std::cout << "SoulByteEngine :: CORE :: WindowManagerModule :: ERROR :: COULD'T CREATE WINDOW" << std::endl;

                return false;
            }

            glfwMakeContextCurrent(this->m_window_handle);

            if (!gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress))
            {
                std::cout << "SoulByteEngine :: CORE :: WINDOW_MANAGER :: ERROR :: CRITICAL :: WINDOW HAS BEEN CREATED, BUT GLAD COULD NOT BE INITIALIZED! " << std::endl;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        bool Window::SetLogging()
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool Window :: IsClosed()
        {
            return this->m_isClosed;
        }

        unsigned int Window::GetWidth()
        {
            return this->m_windowWidth;
        }

        unsigned int Window::GetHeight()
        {
            return this->m_windowHeight;
        }

        const char* Window::GetTitle()
        {
            return this->m_windowTitle;
        }

        void Window::ShowWindowData()
        {
            std::cout << "Window Data:" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Title: " << this->GetTitle() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Width: " << this->GetWidth() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Height: " << this->GetHeight() << std::endl;
        }

        void Window::Clear(float x_pos, float y_pos, float z_pos)
        {
            glClearColor(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

    }
}
```

Application.cpp:

```
#include <WindowManager/WindowManager.hpp>

int main()
{
    if (SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::Window::Init())
    {
        SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::Window first_window(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, "First Fuckin SoulByteEngine Window");
        SoulByteEngineCore::WindowManager::Window second_window(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, "Second Fuckin SoulByteEngine Window");

        while (!first_window.IsClosed() || !second_window.IsClosed())
        {
            if (first_window.ShouldClose())
            {
                first_window.Destroy();
            }
            else
            {
                first_window.onUpdate();
            }
            if (second_window.ShouldClose())
            {
                second_window.Destroy();
            }
            else
            {
                second_window.onUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```